# Offline data with replication/synchronization for Xamarin app on IPhone?

Tags: sqlite, replication, xamarin

What is the safest way to store offline data that can be synchronized with a remote Sql Server  if we build an app using Xamarin on IPhone?

We are currently investigating SiaqoDB and Sqlite.
SiaqoDB does have samples for this, however, the database itself seems somewhat unknown and the community around it is small.

Sqlite has a huge userbase but there don't seem to be any out of the box sync support for this.

Are there other alternatives?
How does SiaqoDB compare to Sqlite here?

Comment: Can you please provide the reference link of those SiaqoDB samples explaining the synchronization of offline database from a xamarin application.

Comment: This question is 3 years old so no :-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know SiaqoDB but i used SQLite on a Xamarin project a while ago.. If you use the SQLite  component from Krueger systems [Krueger](http://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net/) you will have a working database, without synchronization. You could also go for [Zumero SQLite](http://components.xamarin.com/view/zumero/), which includes synchronization to their own server, but i haven´t tried them so i cant compare the two.